# c# class-wide exception handling

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, exception

Is it possible to catch exceptions in a single place in a c# class file?

I'm coding some unit tests in NUnit to test for a WCF Web-Service, and on all methods/tests want to trap a "EndpointNotFoundException" without having to code this for each test.

edit

I guess i wanted to create a descriptive error in this case without having to put an additional catch block in each method, as i do indeed want the test to fail.

As i've done something similar to this in WCF with the FaultException i was interested to know if it was possible in general with C# classes

But the bottom line is that if it fails, it fails! thanks to @TrueWill for stating the obvious ;) and to @Abhijeet Patel for making me think more about how i structure my unit tests

(oh, and apologies for answering my own question ;)

Comment: An unhandled exception in an NUnit test method automatically fails the test. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Do you want your tests to fail if the exception is not thrown?  Or are you looking for a simple way to make your tests _not_ fail if an EndpointNotFoundException _is_ thrown?

Answer (score 3):

In *general*, no - you can only catch locally. There are isolated <s>exceptions</s> occasions when you can do this - ASP.NET MVC controllers and WCF *services* being two examples that leap to mind where the error handling can easily (or easily *enough*) separated.

But in your case - don't you just want to add `[ExpectedException(...)]` to the affected tests?

Comment: Or alternately Assert.Throws/DoesNotThrow for NUnit 2.5: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5.2

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better approach would be to look into injecting the exception handling code with AOP (postsharp) or policy injection?

AFAIK, what you are trying to do is not possible.  You can look into  Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException for centralized exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to achieve this.  The idea is, as you request, to attach some behaviour (exception handling in this case) to all methods in the class.

For example, using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/), you can define the following "exception handler":

```
[Serializable]
class EndpointNotFoundExceptionHandlerAspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.Exception is EndpointNotFoundException)
            eventArgs.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue; // continue without throwing an exception
        else
            base.OnException(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Then add the `EndpointNotFoundExceptionHandlerAspect` to your class definition.  Then every time the `EndpointNotFoundException` is thrown, it will be "handled".

Note:  I make no claims that this is a good idea.  This is merely an example of *how* it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Aspect oriented programming can be done to handle a single type of exception like EndpointNotFoundException..and the exception can be logged somewhere using that..

Answer (score 1):

An approach I've taken to this sort of problem is by providing an `InvokeAction` method which allows you to manage your exception handling in a relatively unified way. This does rely on each of your methods having a similar signature however, naturally you can provide more signatures to cover these other actions:

```
private void InvokeAction (Action<TData> action, data)
{
    try
    {
        action(data);
    }
    catch (EndpointNotFoundException enfe)
    {
        .... unified handling here
    }
    catch (OtherExceptionType oet)
    {
    }
}
```

Using this approach you can then make a call to your service methods which will all have the same try catch block invocation.

e.g. `InvokeAction(AddUser, userData);`

e.g. `InvokeAction(UpdateUser, userData);`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a logging mechanism (or use a third party implementation like log4net) and insert catch blocks everywhere, where the exceptions are logged. In other words, no.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc already pointed out, using an [ExpectedException] on the unit test seems to be the most logical way to go especially for unit tests, where you want to focus on a unit of functionality. if you are doing a lot of try...catch style processing and conditional checking then your unit test isn't really a unit test